# Datalake analytic join

Tags: analytics, azure-data-lake

I have 2 table. I want classified URL who is in table [Activite_Site] I've try the query below, but it doesn't work... Anyone have idea.
    Thank you in advance

```
Table [Categorie]
URL                         CAT
http//www.site.com/business B2B
http//www.site.com/office   B2B
http//www.site.com/job      B2B
http//www.site.com/home     B2C

Table [Actvite_Site]
URL
http//www.site.com/business/page2/test.html
http//www.site.com/business/page3/pagetest/tot.html
http//www.site.com/office/all/tot.html
http//www.site.com/home/holiday/paris.html
http//www.site.com/home/private/moncompte.html

I would like OUTPUT :

URL_SITE                                            CATEGORIE
http//www.site.com/business/page2/test.html         B2B
http//www.site.com/business/page3/pagetest/tot.html B2B
http//www.site.com/office/all/tot.html              B2B
http//www.site.com/home/holiday/paris.html          B2C
http//www.site.com/home/private/moncompte.html      B2C
http//www.site.com/test/pte.html                    Null

My query :

    SELECT A.URL AS URL_SITE
           C.CAT AS  CATEGORIE  
    FROM Actvite_Site as A
        LEFT Categorie as C ON C.URL==A.URL.PadLeft(C.URL.Lenght)
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Error? Unexpected result?

Comment: im seeing typo errors.. or is it the case?

Comment: For simplified, I corrected my query like this:
  SELECT A.URL AS URL_SITE
           C.CAT AS  CATEGORIE  
    FROM Actvite_Site as A
        LEFT Categorie as C ON C.URL==A.URL.PadLeft(10)

Erreur  E_CSC_USER_JOINCOLUMNSEXPECTEDONEACHSIDEOFCONDITION: The expressions A.URL.PadLeft(10) and C.url on each side of the comparison must both be columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE error E_CSC_USER_JOINCOLUMNSEXPECTEDONEACHSIDEOFCONDITION, U-SQL does not currently support derived columns in join conditions.

One way to achieve this might be to find the matched URLs, then the unmatched and UNION them together.

```
@category = SELECT *
     FROM (
        VALUES
            ( "http//www.site.com/business", "B2B" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/office", "B2B" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/job", "B2B" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/home", "B2C" )
        ) AS x(url, cat);


@siteActivity = SELECT *
     FROM (
        VALUES
            ( "http//www.site.com/business/page2/test.html" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/business/page3/pagetest/tot.html" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/office/all/tot.html" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/home/holiday/paris.html" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/home/private/moncompte.html" ),
            ( "http//www.site.com/test/pte.html" )
        ) AS x(url);


// Find matched URLs
@working =
    SELECT sa.url,
           c.cat
    FROM @siteActivity AS sa
         CROSS JOIN
             @category AS c
         WHERE sa.url.Substring(0, c.url.Length) == c.url;


// Combine the matched and unmatched URLs
@output =
    SELECT url,
           cat
    FROM @working

    UNION ALL

    SELECT url,
           (string) null AS cat
    FROM @siteActivity AS sa
         ANTISEMIJOIN
             @working AS w
         ON sa.url == w.url;



OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way though.