# How to use Not equal to condition in U-SQL?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to write a U-SQL query to replicate the same logic which SQL query does as below.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tb1 
LEFT JOIN tb2 
ON tb1.id=tb2.id AND tb1.pid!=tb2.pid;
```

Since U-SQL doesn't support Not equal to in join condition `(tb1.pid!=tb2.pid)`.

Is there a way to achieve this logic in USQL?

Comment: Consider concatenating the columns and joining on that or this may be possible using UNION and ANTISEMIJOIN as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362132/datalake-analytic-join).

Answer (score 1):

First, please note that using any comparison operator other than equality in a `JOIN` clause usually degrades the performance of the query, and I personally would consider it bad style. After all, it is a `JOIN` clause and not a `WHERE` clause, meaning that it should tell the DBMS which rows to "link" together (and not which rows to *not* "link").

This is true even if the DBMS allows the use of all sorts of comparison operators in the `JOIN` clause.

Having said this, just move the `!=` comparison into a `WHERE` clause (where it belongs to anyway due to the reasons mentioned above):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb1 
LEFT JOIN tb2 
ON tb1.id=tb2.id
WHERE tb1.pid!=tb2.pid;
```

This will produce exactly the same results as your original query.